# Initial jump in loss with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, mathematical-optimization

Suppose I have a saved model that is nearly at the minimum, but with some room for improvement. For example, the loss (as reported by tf.keras.Models.model.evaluate() ) might be 11.390, and I know that the model can go down to 11.300.

The problem is that attempts to refine this model (using tf.keras.Models.model.fit()) consistently result in the weights receiving an initial 'jolt' during the first epoch, which sends the loss way upwards. After that, it starts to decrease, but it does not always converge on the correct minimum (and may not even get back to where it started.)

It looks like this:

tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.0002):

```
0 11.982
1 11.864
2 11.836
3 11.822
4 11.809
5 11.791
(...)
15 11.732
```

tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001):

```
0 14.667
1 11.483
2 11.400
3 11.380
4 11.371
5 11.365
```

tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.00001):

```
0 12.288
1 11.760
2 11.699
3 11.650
4 11.666
5 11.601
```

Dataset with 30M observations, batch size 500K in all cases.

I can mitigate this by turning the learning rate way down, but then it takes forever to converge.

Is there any way to prevent training from going "wild" at the beginning, without impacting the long-term convergence rate?

Answer (score 0):

> As you tried decreasing the learning rate is the way to go.

E.g. learning rate = 0.00001

```
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.00001)
```

Especially with Adam that should be promising, since the learning rate is at the same time an upper bound for the step size.

On top of that you could try [learning rate scheduling](https://machinelearningmastery.com/using-learning-rate-schedules-deep-learning-models-python-keras/), where you set the learning rate according to your predefined schedule.

Also I feel that from what you show when you decreased the learning rate, this does not seem to be too bad, in terms of convergence rate.
Maybe another hyperparameter you could tune in your case would be to reduce the batch size, to decrease computation cost per update.

*Note:*
I find the term "not the right minimum" rather misleading. To further understand nonconvex optimization for artificial neural networks, I would like to Point to the [deep learning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) of Ian Goodfellow et al